# Adding a custom listener inside a broadcast receiver gives NPE in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, listener, android-broadcastreceiver, custom-event

I have been stuck with a problem here.I am trying to listen to connectivity changes by implementing a broadcast receiver.Also I have initialised a custom listener within the broadcast receiver so as to communicate to the activity about the connectivity changes to show a Crouton Toast.The code for the various classes as below :

The broadcast receiver :

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private NetworkStateListener networkStateListener;

    public NetworkStateReceiver() {
    }

    public NetworkStateReceiver(NetworkStateListener networkStateListener) {
        this.networkStateListener = networkStateListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("test", "Network connectivity change ::: " + this.networkStateListener);
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {

            NetworkInfo ni = (NetworkInfo) intent.getExtras().get(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if (ni != null && ni.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                Log.i("test", "Network " + ni.getTypeName() + " connected");
                networkStateListener.onConnected();
            }
        }
        if (intent.getExtras().getBoolean(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, Boolean.FALSE)) {
            Log.d("test", "There's no network connectivity");
            networkStateListener.onDisconnected();
        }
    }
}
```

The custom listener interface :

```
public interface NetworkStateListener {

    public void onConnected();

    public void onDisconnected();
}
```

The activity in which the listener is implemented and receiver is registered for connectivity changes :

```
    public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NetworkStateListener {
     private NetworkStateReceiver mReceiver;
     private LocalBroadcastManager mBroadcastManager;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
      mBroadcastManager =    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(HomeActivity.this);
        mReceiver = new NetworkStateReceiver(HomeActivity.this);
    }

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        mBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
    }
```

And this is the manifest entry :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

 <application
        android:name=".TestApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

<receiver android:name=".shared.receivers.NetworkStateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have no idea why the networkstateListener is not getting initialised.It gives a null pointer denoting that NetWorkStateListener may not be initialised.Can someone please help me out with this ? I have achieved this in the past, but with a custom broadcast and not with these kind of system broadcasts.

Answer (score 3):

The `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` broadcast is sent by the system. This means a couple of things for your current setup.

1. The instance of your `BroadcastReceiver` that you're registering with `LocalBroadcastManager` will never receive that broadcast, as `LocalBroadcastManager` only handles broadcasts originating from within your app.
2. Registering your Receiver class in the manifest means that the system will instantiate a new instance of the Receiver to handle each broadcast. Since those instances will not have been passed an instance of your `Activity` as a listener, `networkStateListener` will be null in `onReceive()`, which is most likely where your current `NullPointerException` is coming from.

Depending on what your desired behavior is, you have a few options to choose from.

If you just want to be notified of connectivity changes while the `Activity` is running:

1. Register an instance of the Receiver with the `Context#registerReceiver()` method instead, and remove the `<receiver>` entry from the manifest. If you make `NetworkStateReceiver` an inner class of `HomeActivity`, you won't need the interface.
2. Use `LocalBroadcastManager` to communicate between `NetworkStateReceiver` and your `Activity`, instead of your listener `interface`. You could use an extra on the `Intent` to indicate connectivity state, or alternatively use different actions to distinguish.
3. Use some other event bus implementation to communicate between the Receiver and the `Activity`.

If you want to be notified of changes even when your app isn't running:

4. Start your `Activity` from the Receiver with an extra attached to the `Intent` to indicate connectivity state. This could also handle the case of your `Activity` already running, if you set the `Activity`'s `launchMode` to `singleTask` or `singleTop`, and override its `onNewIntent()` method.

In any case, passing your `Activity` as a listener to your `BroadcastReceiver` isn't really necessary.